# Dropzone.js How to re-send Form after Form Field Server-side validation failed

Tags: jquery, dropzone.js

I use Zend Framework 2 and have implemented Dropzone.js. I am still very new to Dropzone and have now run into the following problem. I send my File together with the rest of my Form Fields. With PHP I check if the Form is valid, if not I return the Error Messages and attach it via jQuery to the Form. That all works fine, but unfortunately after I now fill out all the Form Fields, I am not able anymore to click on the submit Button. How can I achieve that? It just sounds like a normal process, but I must be doing something very wrong. Can anyone give me a hint?

```
  Dropzone.options.myDropzone = {
      autoProcessQueue: false,
      uploadMultiple: true,
      parallelUploads: 100,
      maxFiles: 1,
      maxFilesize: 10, //mb
      acceptedFiles: 'image/*',
      addRemoveLinks: true,
      autoDiscover: false,
      previewsContainer: '.dropzone-previews', //used for specifying the previews div
      clickable: '.dz-clickable', //used this but now i cannot click on previews div to showup the file select dialog box

      accept: function(file, done) {
                console.log("uploaded");
                done();
            },

      // The setting up of the dropzone
      init: function() {
            var myDropzone = this;


            $('#myDropzone').on("submit", function(e) {
              if(myDropzone.files.length > 0) {
                 e.preventDefault();
                 e.stopPropagation();
                 myDropzone.processQueue();
              }
            });         

            myDropzone.processQueue(); // this will submit your form to the specified action path

            // after this, your whole form will get submitted with all the inputs + your files and the php code will remain as usual 
            // REMEMBER you DON'T have to call ajax or anything by yourself, dropzone will take care of that
            // First change the button to actually tell Dropzone to process the queue.


            this.on("maxfilesexceeded", function(file){
                    alert("You have exceeded the maximum files allowed !");
                    this.removeFile(file);
                });      

            // Listen to the sendingmultiple event. In this case, it's the sendingmultiple event instead
            // of the sending event because uploadMultiple is set to true.
            this.on("sendingmultiple", function() {
              // Gets triggered when the form is actually being sent.
              // Hide the success button or the complete form.
            });

            this.on("successmultiple", function(files, response) {

               if (response.status == true)
               {
                  window.location.replace(response.redirect);
               }else{   
                  $.each(response.error, function(key, value){
                    $('[name="'+key+'"]').parent().append(getErrorHtml(response[key], value));
                 });
               }
            });

            this.on("errormultiple", function(files, response) {
              // Gets triggered when there was an error sending the files.
              // Maybe show form again, and notify user of error
            });
      },

    };

 function getErrorHtml(key , value)
 {
   var html = '<ul id="errors-'+key+'" class="errors">';
       html += '<li>' + value + '</li>';
       html += '</ul>';
   return html;
```

}

Comment: This dropbox issue may help,
https://github.com/enyo/dropzone/issues/717

Comment: did you ever solve this? i have not been able to get the linked code implemented properly in my script.

Comment: @GauravSinghJantwal can you please help with this topic - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39065688/dropzone-js-requeue-rejected-files-trying-to-implement-github-answer-int